# Does ScrollViewComponent from Kendo UI for Angular 2 support individual pages?

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

The documentation and samples for the ScrollViewComponent just explain how to use the component with a data-bound template.
Isn't it intended to be used like a tabcontrol or wizard?
I.e.

```
<kendo-scrollview ...>
  <kendo-scrollpage>
    <my-component></my-component>
  </kendo-scrollpage>
  <kendo-scrollpage>
    <p>And now for something completey different ...</p>
  </kendo-scrollpage>
</kendo-scrollview>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, no, this scenario is out of the scope of the ScrollView component. It is built around the idea of databound templates. Conceptually similar to the mobile [Kendo ScrollView widget](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scrollview/index).